# Steam rate of supercritical steam turbine

Tags: thermodynamics

I've heard that supercritical steam turbines are more efficient than subcritical units.  My research always gives me the answer of "less fuel used per MW output".
But what I want to know is the steam rate (requirement).
For instance, does a supercritical turbine require 4X the steam rate of a subcritical turbine, and therefore 4X the fuel is burned, BUT it puts out 4.2X the power ... so its more efficient...    ???

Comment: Efficiency depends on the source temperature and the sink temperature.  Without specifying temperatures and pressures, there's no way to answer the question.  As a start, Google heat engine efficiency to get an idea of how much heat can be converted into useful work.